# where app's settings are stored?

Tags: settings

Where are stored the settings of the apps in Android (6)? I'd like to modify something in [Librera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pdf.reader):

- Disable the bookmark box
- Hiding words in top left corner

Comment: Under `/data/data/com.foobnix.pdf.reader/`

Answer (score 1):

By design of the Android OS on a regular phone you can't modify settings of an app other than by the app itself. Therefore the best way is to search for an option in the "Librera app" itself.

If there is no option to change what you want you may have a chance if the app allows app backup via Android Debug Bridge (`adb`). In such a case you can perform a backup of the data of the app to your PC, decrypt it there (using [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor)), modify it, re-pack it to a backup file and then restore it using `adb`.

Only on rooted devices you can directly access the app-private files in which the data is stored.

Update: I have checked the Libera app (com.foobnix.pdf.reader). It declares `allowBackup="true"` therefore the outlined way using `adb backup com.foobnix.pdf.reader` should work for this app. However you still need to understand the settings file format and last but not least there have to be a setting that does what you want.